# Documentation does not open on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter

While learning the matplotlib library, I learned about the 'shift+tab' combination. I was looking there and writing my codes. Today I opened Jupyter Notebook again, but the 'shift+tab' combination does not work. How can I access documentation on Jupyter?

"shift+tab", right click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "Shift+Tab" is not working for you, there could be a few reasons for this. Try restarting the kernel by clicking the "Kernel" menu and selecting "Restart."

Answer (score 0):

Along with 'shift + tab' you can also access the documentation by `help()`

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#help

```
import matplotlib
help(matplotlib)
```

OR

```
print(matplotlib.__doc__)
```

OR restart your kernel and then try:

```
matplotlib (press'Shift + Tab')
```

Answer (score 0):

My experience has been shift-tab does not work if

a) kernel is currently executing some
b) code is written using method chaining
c) The object is not defined. That is the IDE does not know the data type.

To give an example

```
df = pd.read_csv("some_file.csv")
df.sum()  # shift tab will fail for this line if the above line has not been run
```